# Python bind UDP Socket to low port

Tags: python, sockets, udp, bind

I want to bind an UDP Server to a low port (e.g. Port 500) but I always get the error

*[Errno 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions*

I tried to run the program with Administrator rights, but i get the same error.

When I try this with a TCP socket it works fine. Also when I use a high port > 1023

This is my code:

```
def UDP_connect(ip, port_number, delay, output, source_ip='0', source_port=0):
    UDPsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    UDPsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    UDPsock.settimeout(delay)
    if source_ip != '0' and source_port > 0:
        UDPsock.bind((source_ip, source_port))

    try:
        data = "Hello"
        s.sendto(data,(ip,port_number))
        if len(s.recvfrom(1024)) > 0:
            output[port_number] = 'Listening'
        else:
            output[port_number] = ''
    except:
        output[port_number] = ''

    UDPsock.close()
```

Comment: UDP port number 500 is reserved: 'isakmp  500  udp  isakmp', and so are the adjacent ones. Why are you using them?